# How to use bearer token with two asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, token, bearer-token

i have two project both of them are asp.net web api

with one of the web api i have the functionality to create bearer token

Web api 1 :

Startup.Auth.cs file :

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions();

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
```

and to create a new token i am using this function :

```
      public static string CreateTokenForAuthUser(string username ,string role)
      {

        AuthList authlist = new AuthList();
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SomeRule"));

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
        ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

        string token = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

        return token;

      }
```

all working fine to create bearer token and use it on this web api

i would like to know how can i use the same bearer token that was created on the web api 1 with another asp.net web api that i have for using the same authorization rules on controllers (assuming they have the same functionality )

Thanks !

Comment: Hey man, its old but... Can you provide the solution plz ? I'm in the same scenario...

Comment: I'm still in the same scenario

Answer (score 0):

Does it help

```
var client = new RestClient("http://yourhost/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=password&username=usernameEndcode&password=passwordEncodeValue", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

**UPDATE**

After get token you can use it like this

```
var token = response.accessToken; //not sure accessToken is corrected here but you can easy debug to get correct property
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:62301/api/values");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\n   \n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: let me understand it
i just making a request for a new token from the web api 2 to the web api 1 ?
how can i use token that already created on the web api 1?